# Using Full Text Indexing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, full-text-indexing

I've a question about the best way to get product data searching by name. Which one is better way to do that?

1. `SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName = 'Samsung Note 2'`
2. Creating a full text index for `ProductName` and get matching products that way

In brief, can my query be faster if I create a full text index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you searching..

- whole ProductName? Then use a normal index
- individual words or fuzzy matches in a ProductName? Use full text serach

Comment: I mean, is full text index have any positive affect on normal index ?

Comment: @SaygınKarahan: no, they are separate and have different operators = vs CONTAINS for example